# Bacula: bacula-dir.conf Console ACL - One Console, Multiple Clients

Tags: bacula

In bacula-dir.conf:

I was wondering if it were possible to have one "Client" entry for each client, but only have one "Console" entry for ALL clients -- to achieve this end:
  - Each client can only run their own backup and restore jobs

Currently, I only see examples of each client having both a "Client" entry and a "Console" entry in order to restrict job access to their own jobs using ACL.

I'm using Webmin to administer Bacula and it gives me access to "Client" entries, but does not let me configure a "Console" entry for each user.  If I can skip making a "Console" entry for each user, I can avoid editing bacula-dir.conf all together.  This would make it much easier to administer the whole system.

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... looks like I cant.... but I have found a work around for myself.

```
@|"sh -c 'for f in /etc/bacula/consoles/*.conf ; do echo @${f} ; done'"
```

This goes in the bacula-dir.conf which cases bacula to include all files in a directory.  Then I created a script to add consoles and ACLs based on a template using sed.

```
sed -e "s;%CLIENT_NAME%;$1;g" console.tmplt > $1.conf
```

console.tmplt:

```
Console {
    Name = %CLIENT_NAME%
    Password = "%CLIENT_NAME%RAND0MxEX7RAx5TUFF"
    .
    .
    .
    ACLS.....
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Then run:

```
createconsole.sh Client.Name
```

Then in Webmin, there is a Run Command and Custom Commands modules what can run this script to create the Console entries simply.